# Improving CoreGraphics performance on iPhone4

Tags: iphone

I'm compositing two (static) images, several times a second.   This code runs pretty snappily on the 3Gs, and really slowly on the iPhone4.   TimeProfiler reveals that the call to UIImage drawAtPoint: ends up calling something very expensive called "argb_sample_RGBA21".   This routine is never called on the 3Gs.   Is there some byte-order conversion that I could perform on the static images once, thus saving this byte-order conversion?

```
+ (UIImage * ) createInterpolatedImageBetween: (UIImage *) imageA
                                     andImage:  (UIImage *) imageB
                                     forValue: (float) fractionalValue {

      UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(imageA.size.width, imageA.size.height), YES, 0.0); 

      [imageA drawAtPoint: CGPointMake(0,0)];

      [imageB drawAtPoint: CGPointMake(0,0) 
                blendMode: kCGBlendModeNormal 
                    alpha: fractionalValue];


      UIImage *answer = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); 
      UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
      return answer;
```

}

Comment: in iPhone4 images can be much more bigger than 3GS, I think this is the reason. Make sure you are processing the image of the size you want ;)

Answer (score 0):

Core Graphics is inherently slow because it runs exclusively on the CPU and does not take advantage of graphics hardware.  Using [CISourceOverCompositing](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CISourceOverCompositing) optionally combined with a CICategoryCompositeOperation from that same page will give you a significant performance gain, but only if you are targeting iOS 5 or greater.

Here's a good core image intro:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/5689/beginning-core-image-in-ios-5